# YYMM to date time python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dateframe column in Python that is in the format `YYMM`.  E.g `January 1996` is `9601`.

I'm having a hard time converting it from 9601 to a useable date time format. I want the new format to be `01-01-1996`.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I tried `pd.to_datetime` function but it's not getting the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses. You can also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['9601', '9705']})
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%y%m')
print (df)
         col
0 1996-01-01
1 1997-05-01
```